# Why can neither an "if" branch for speed < 70 nor speed > 70 fire?

Tags: python

This is my problem

You are provided with 2 input values which determine the speed of 2 cars.

```
If both cars are travelling at more than 70 then output ‘2 fast cars’
If one car only is moving at more than 70, output ‘1 fast car’
Otherwise output ‘no fast cars’
```

This is my code

```
import sys
speed1 = int(sys.argv[1])
speed2 = int(sys.argv[2])


if speed1 > 70 and speed2 > 70:
  print ('2 fast cars')
if speed1 > 70 and speed2 < 70:
  print ('1 fast car')
if speed1 < 70 and speed2 > 70:
  print ('1 fast cars')
if speed1 < 70 and speed2 < 70:
  print ('no fast cars')
```

this is my error

```
Program Failed for Input: 70 70
Expected Output: no fast cars
Your Program Output:
```

I'm sure this is just a syntax error but i cant find it, thanks

Comment: Well what is not clear about the error? You compare with `70`, but no case is fired if one of the two (or both) are exactly 70.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that it's `just a syntax error` if my code is running.

Comment: BTW, in general, it'll help provide a much better reception here if you attempt to build a [mcve] isolating the specific place where the code doesn't do what you expect before asking your question. So, you might have just two lines: One assigning `speed1 = 70`, the other running, `print(speed1 < 70)`, and then have the question ask why the output is `False` if you expect it to be `True`.

Comment: (If you didn't think through your code enough to identify the specific condition you expect to be `True` that is instead `False`, then you aren't yet ready to ask a question here).

Answer (score 4):

The error is quite descriptive: you forgot to take a case into account: when one (or both cars) drive at 70 (kmph or mhp). In that case all of the `if` statements will fail, and so no output is written.

A quick fix is to rewrite `<` into `<=` (such that it includes 70):

```
import sys
speed1 = int(sys.argv[1])
speed2 = int(sys.argv[2])


if speed1 > 70 and speed2 > 70:
  print ('2 fast cars')
if speed1 > 70 and speed2 <= 70:
  print ('1 fast car')
if speed1 <= and speed2 > 70:
  print ('1 fast cars')  # probably a typo? cars -> car
if speed1 <= 70 and speed2 <= 70:
  print ('no fast cars')
```

But actually this still is not very elegant: you repeat yourself a lot, and usually that is an *antipattern*. You can use `else`, and `elif` to make the code less verbose, like for instance:

```
import sys
speed1 = int(sys.argv[1])
speed2 = int(sys.argv[2])


if speed1 > 70 and speed2 > 70:
  print ('2 fast cars')
elif speed1 > 70 or speed2 > 70:
  print ('1 fast car')
else:
  print ('no fast cars')
```

So first we check if both values are greater than 70. If that is the case we have two fast cars. If that fails, but one of the two is greater than 70, then we have on fast car. Finally if that test fails as well, then we know that both cars have a speed less than or equal to 70, so in that case there are no fast cars.

An `elif` is basically a condition that is checked in case the `if` condition fails. So in case the `if` condition fails, we fallback on the `elif` condition. If that condition then succeeds, we will run the body of the `elif` part. If not we faillback to the `else` case.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it my assignments haven't really made elif clear.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your program does not handle the case where the speed *is* 70, it only checks for >70 and <70.  Thus, if fails when given a speed of 70.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any syntax errors. In the script you gave you have said that if the speed is more (`>`) or less (`<`).  In no case have you given the option when both cars are equal to each other.

You can do this in two ways:

```
if speed1 == 70 and speed2 == 70:
    print ('2 fast cars both at 70')
```

or if you want to make it so it is less or equal you can use:

```
if speed1 <= 70 and speed2 <= 70:
    print ('2 fast cars either both at 70 or under 70')
```

or more or equal then you can do this:

```
if speed1 >= 70 and speed2 >= 70:
    print ('2 fast cars either both at 70 or over 70')
```